# How to create routes to full page New / Edit template in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have a list controller, with Edit links for each element. How would I render the Edit template into a full page?

A common use case is that the form page is large, and it doesn't make sense rendering it below the list (which can also be quite long).

Rendering the Edit template inside the parent's outlet destroys the hierarchy, and the back / cancel button wouldn't rerender the list. So it seems like it needs to be a child of the list (and rendered in the list template's outlet), yet it must hide the list template without hiding itself.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across this 'problem' several times when building toy applications. My solution has been to add a template for the resource. So for example, if you were building an address book, your current problem/solution looks like:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('person', { path: '/person' }, function() {
    this.route('index', { path: '/' });
    this.route('edit', { path: '/:person_id/edit' });
  });
});
```

And your templates might look like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person/index">
    <ul>
        {{#each model}}
            <li>{{name}} - {{#linkTo person.edit this}}Edit{{/linkTo}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>

    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person/edit">
    {{#each model}}
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name"}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

To stop rendering the edit template in the index route's router, you would add the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person">
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

And remove the {{outlet}} from the person.index template.

This way, your index and edit templates are both children of the person resource and should load in the person template's {{outlet}} rather than in the person.index {{outlet}}.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps. The models are the same so even if the templates are rendered as children, they still share the same data. Updating the model in the Edit Form updates the bindings to the List. Also, I have both full page forms (siblings) and modal forms (where the list must appear in the background -> child outlet required). I need a way to force Ember Data to rollback model changes when clicking some other link or pasting a different link (which don't trigger the rollback action, like the cancel button does)