# Ember.JS: There is no route named blah

Tags: ember.js

I am getting this error:

```
Assertion Failed: You attempted to define a `{{link-to "companies.show"}}` but did not pass the parameters required for generating its dynamic segments. There is no route named companies.show
```

But I do have that route in `router.js` and is was working before I added two new routes along with a component for editing/adding records. But it is indeed gone right now - I can nav directly to it either. So I think I have an error in a different part of my that is dominoing into my route.

```
// router.js 
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('states');
  this.route('companyTypes');

  this.route('companies', function() {
    this.route('show', {path: '/:company_id'});
    this.route('new');
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:company_id'});
  });

  this.route('counties', {path : '/counties/:state'});
});

// routes/companies.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('company');
  }
});

// routes/companies/show.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.get('store').findRecord('company', params.company_id);
  }
});
```

I am passing the model parameter in the `link-to` and the show route has its model hook.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the problem was I duplicated the same route in router.js

```
// router.js
this.route('companies', function() {
    this.route('show', {path: '/:company_id'});
    this.route('new');
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:company_id'});
  });
```

Both show and edit have the same route: If you nav to `http://localhost:4200/companies/1` are you supposed to go to show or edit? edit overwrites show because it comes last. Move show after edit:

```
// router.js
this.route('companies', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:company_id'});
    this.route('show', {path: '/:company_id'});
  });
```

And show starts working, but edit will break.

So you need to do something like this:

```
// router.js
this.route('companies', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('edit', {path: '/edit/:company_id'});
    this.route('show', {path: '/:company_id'});
  });
```

Your routes are now:

```
http://localhost:4200/companies/1
http://localhost:4200/companies/edit/1
```

Comment: FYI:  The conventional edit path would be `/:company_id/edit`

Comment: @dwenzel, What is your source for that? I do want to follow the right Ember conventions out the door. The one sample project I have studied that has an edit does it the way I have above, but there is no guarantee they got it right.

Comment: I think it's just a REST API convention, although I can't find a specific source.  It seems logical, though: typically urls are like a nested folder structure:  `/companies/edit...` looks like your editing all the companies, whereas `/companies/:company_id/edit` looks like you're editing the specific company, which is what you want.

Comment: I did find a few examples out there: http://ember.vicramon.com/routing-in-ember,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957654/how-to-create-routes-to-full-page-new-edit-template-in-emberjs

Comment: @dwenzel, Ok I'll buy that. Seems like an Ember specific (or maybe a general RESTish framework) thing rather than an actual REST thing. In REST you have the same URI and change the verb in the header for a "view" or an "edit".